# Best practices with regard the read of vast amounts of files in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to deal with a vast amount of `.DAT` files which contain measurements per second (each line represents a second) from an electrical device.

I have more than 5000 files each of which is about 160 KiB (not that much actually), but I am finding it difficult to find an efficient or recommended way to deal with this kind of problem: **create an object that summmarizes each file content**.

This is my file structure:

```
feeder/
     CT40CA18_20190101_000000_60P_40000258.DAT
     CT40CA18_20190101_010000_60P_40000258.DAT
     CT40CA18_20190101_020000_60P_40000258.DAT
     CT40CA18_20190101_030000_60P_40000258.DAT
     CT40CA18_20190101_040000_60P_40000258.DAT
     ....
     ....
     ....
     CT40CA18_20190812_010000_60P_40000258.DAT
```

My current code in Java Spark (2.1.1 version) is:

```
public class Playground {

    private static final SparkSession spark = new SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dataset<FeederFile> feederFileDataset = spark
                .read()
                .textFile("resources/CT40CA18/feeder/*.DAT")
                .map(new ParseFeederFile(), Encoders.bean(FeederFile.class));

    }
}
```

`ParseFeederFile` is:

```
package transformations.map;

import model.FeederFile;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;

public class ParseFeederFile implements MapFunction<String, FeederFile> {

    private StringBuilder fileContent;

    public ParseFeederFile() {
        fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public FeederFile call(String s) throws Exception {
        return new FeederFile().withContent(fileContent.append(s).append("\n").toString());
    }
}
```

and `FeederFile`

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class FeederFile implements Serializable {

    private String content;

    public FeederFile() {}

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public FeederFile withContent(final String content) {
        this.content = content;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when map invokes `call` the string that is passed represents a line of a `.DAT` file. Therefore there is a vast and unnecessary creation of `FeederFile` objects. Another problem is that `textFile` does not differentiate between different files so everything is being appended to the same object (i.e, content of all files are in attribute `content` in `FeederFile` class)

I managed this naive way for retrieving all the content (I do not want all the content itself, but to create a sort of object that summarises information about the `.DAT` file, like the lines count, and some statistics based upon the data)

Does any of you come up with an idea on how can I create a `FeederFile` per `.DAT`?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(...)
```

> SparkContext’s whole text files method, i.e., sc.wholeTextFiles in
>   Spark Shell, creates a PairRDD with the key being the file name with a
>   path. It’s a full path like
>   “hdfs://aa1/data/src_data/stage/test_files/collection_vk/current_snapshot/*”.
>   The value is the whole content of file in String.

Comment: Can I somewhat leverage the use of this method by using the ``SparkSession`` class?

Comment: `sparkSession.sparkContext`